# Sorting Attributes in xsl with other elements surrounding it

Tags: xml, xslt

Been frusterated by this problem for a couple days now.

I'm trying to copy an xml file while sorting an attribute of a nested element.  What i've got I feel should work

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:my="my:my">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" /> 
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
     </xsl:copy>      
</xsl:template>        
  <xsl:template match="PrProduct">
     <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@* " >
            <xsl:sort select="@TEC"  order="descending" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>             
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

heres the xml

```
<body>
<issueobject>
<page>
</page>
<prproduct TEC="TOR">
</prproduct>
<prproduct TEC="UVA">
<partPage>
</partPage>
</issueobject>
</body>
```

I think the problem lies in that theres elements at the same level on either side of the element I'm sorting as in playing around I can get the data to sort but wind up missing the data after/before.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What your stylesheet does is to sort the *contents* of the `PrProduct` elements by the value of (non-existing) `TEC` attributes. What you need is a template matching the *parent* of `PrProduct`, in your case `issueobject`, which can then sort the `PrProduct` elements. Something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="issueobject">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="PrProduct[1]/preceding-sibling::*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="PrProduct">
            <xsl:sort select="@TEC" order="descending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="PrProduct[1]/following-sibling::*[not(self::PrProduct)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

(Note that this example ignores the text children of `issueobject`.)

Answer (score 0):

You current template is trying to sort the child nodes of the **prproduct** element, and finding the cupboard bare. What you could do instead, is change the template to match only the first **prproduct** element and then sort that and the following **prproduct** siblings

```
<xsl:template match="prproduct[1]">
     <xsl:for-each select="self::*|following-sibling::prproduct">
        <xsl:sort select="@TEC" order="descending"/>
        <!-- Copy element -->
     </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

In addition to this, all you would need is a template to stop the other **prproduct** elements being output twice

```
<xsl:template match="prproduct"/>
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="node() | @*" name="identity">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="prproduct[1]">
       <xsl:for-each select="self::*|following-sibling::prproduct">
         <xsl:sort select="@TEC" order="descending"/>
         <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="prproduct"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is output

```
<body>
   <issueobject>
       <page></page>
       <prproduct TEC="UVA"></prproduct>
       <prproduct TEC="TOR"></prproduct>
       <partPage></partPage>
   </issueobject>
</body>
```

Note the use of the named template, to avoid duplicate coding of the identity template.